# replacing file name and content : shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have written the code for replacing content but quite confused with replacing file name, both in the same script. I want my script to run this way:

```
suppose I give input : ./myscript.sh abc xyz

abc is my string to be replaced 
xyz is the string to replace with
```

If some directory or any subdirectory or file in it has name abc, that should also change to xyz.

Here is my code:

```
filepath="/misc/home3/babitasandooja/fol1"
for file in $(grep -lR $1 $filepath)
do
sed  -i "s/$1/$2/g" $file
echo "Modified: " $file
done
```

Now How should I code to replace the filename as well.

I tried:

```
if( *$1*==$file )
then  
rename $1 $2 $filepath
fi
```

and

```
find -iname $filepath -exec mv $1 $2 \;
```

but any of then is not working correctly. What should I do? Which approach should I take?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$1 str=$2 rep=$3
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    sed  -i "s/$str/$rep/g" -- "$file"
    base=${file##*/} dir=${file%/*}
    [[ $base == *"$str"* ]] && mv "$file" "$dir/${base//$str/$rep}"
done < <(exec grep -ZFlR "$str" "$dir")
```

Usage:

```
bash script.sh dir string replacement
```

Note: `rename` would also rename the directory part.

- `grep -Z` makes it produce null-delimited outputs. i.e. it produces output which is composed of filenames in which everything is separated by `0x00`.
- `-d ''` makes `read` read input delimited by `0x00`; `-r` prevents
  backslashes to be interpreted; and `IFS=` prevents word splitting with `IFS`.
- `IFS= read -rd ''` makes read read input with delimiter of `0
- `base=${file##*/}` removes the directory part. It's the same as base=$(basename "$file")
- `dir=${file%/*}` removes the file part.
- `[[ $base == *"$str"* ]]` checks if the filename has something that could be renamed. `&&` makes the command that follows it execute if the previous returns zero (true) code. Think of it as a single link `if` statement.
- `"$dir/${base//$str/$rep}"` forms the new filename. `${base//$str/$rep}` replaces anything in `$base` that matches value of `$str` and replace it with value of `$rep`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It's working fine. Could you please explain it as I am new to shell scripting.

Comment: Thanks again...:) but if my directory is named as abc, its getting replaced by xyz. But if its abc.txt, then not. What change do I need to do ??

Comment: @user3542109 You can just use `rename` I suppose but that's going to be more complicated as you have to also manually create the directory. I think I misread your question so I'll just pass :) I hope it helped you anyhow.